# Is time complexity $O(n^{n/log(n)})$ considered subexponential time?

Tags: time-complexity, runtime-analysis

If there is an algorithm with time complexity $O(n^{n/log(n)})$, is that already exponential time or still subexponential time?

It shouldn't be considered quasi-polynomial since the exponent is also depending on $n$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$n^{\tfrac{n}{\log_2 n}} = (2^{\log_2 n})^{\tfrac{n}{\log_2 n}} = 2^{\tfrac{n}{\log_2 n}\times \log_2 n} = 2^n$$

Comment: Thanks, maybe I should have put a little bit more thought to it :P